# Prevent taps from hiding the soft keyboard

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently working on the search feature of a PWA. While searching, some toggle buttons that act as filters are shown, and I would like the user to feel as if they  were part of the input, without making the soft keyboard retract on mobile devices when the user taps on them. However, when the buttons are pressed, the search box loses focus and the keyboard is retracted. Is there any way to overcome this issue?

Here is a short snippet that can be built upon for testing:

```html
<input placeholder="I open the soft keyboard">
<button>…and I shouldn't close it</button>
```

Comment: You'd probably have to detect the user pressing on the buttons and write code to send the focus back to the textbox. Clicking/pressing on a button automatically focuses it - I don't think there's any way to avoid that.

Comment: @ADyson I had thought of that, but it would likely mess with accessibility…

Comment: Unless someone knows better than me, then in that case I think you are probably out of options. The keyboard is a feature of the browser (or even the o/s) and I'm not sure you can control when it appears from within a JavaScript environment

Comment: Hmm… I'll probably give up on some accessibility then. Thanks for your help though 